# Does FileStream.Seek() with SeekOrigin.Begin optimize for when no seeking is necessary?

Tags: c#, filestream

I have a class that reads image data a row at a time from large files using `FileStream`.  Internally, the files are broken into chunks, each of which looks like this:

```
=================
| Header        |
=================
| Data I Want   |
=================
| Data I Ignore |
=================
```

To read a row of data, I calculate which chunk has the row I want, `Seek()` to the appropriate offset, and read a fixed number of bytes.  When reading multiple rows from within a single chunk, I could actually skip all `Seek()` calls but the first, because the pointer is already where I want it after a `Read()`.  But I need to `Seek()` when jumping to a new chunk.  For simplicity, I always calculate the next row's absolute offset in the file and `Seek()` to it using `SeekOrigin.Begin`.  Is `FileStream.Seek()` (or the underlying `SetFilePointer()` native function) optimized to recognize that a given seek is a no-op?  If not, I should probably optimize my own code, as it's not exactly lightning-fast.

Comment: _"it's not exactly lightning-fast"_ -- I doubt that has anything to do with how often you call `Seek()`. Of course, without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the current state of the code and a clearly stated performance goal, it's not possible to discuss in any useful or precise way what you may or may not need in the way of optimization. If you care about performance and want to know how different implementations and/or optimizations affect performance, you need to **test it yourself**. Just write the code each way you want to consider and compare the results.

Comment: The reason I asked the question is that I overestimated the work involved in optimizing out the unnecessary `Seek()` calls and was hoping someone would just know off the top of their head that Microsoft's code already made this optimization.  I was worried about the possibility that, for reasons I might not guess, seeking with SeekOrigin.Begin would actually require the HD to find the start of the file and read sequentially to the specified location.  I was only planning to optimize if this was true.  But in the end, adding the check to my code was easier than I thought, so I added it.

Comment: _" I was worried about the possibility that...seeking with SeekOrigin.Begin would actually require the HD to find the start of the file and read sequentially to the specified location"_ -- I haven't seen the Windows code, but I can practically guarantee that _that_ is _not_ the case. Frankly, your attempt to "optimize" this may well have resulted in _poorer_ performance; at the very least, you now have to track the file position separately, or even worse you are looking at the `Position` property, which incurs the same user-to-kernel transition that `Seek()` does.

Comment: Sounds like a classic "premature optimization" to me, and a perfect example of why one should always include reliable performance _measurement_ as part of any optimization work. Fact is, you've made a change to your code and I'll bet you have no real idea what it's done to performance, good or bad.

Comment: Right you were!  Started sprinkling StopWatches through the code and found out I was CPU bound doing unnecessary calculations in nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be Yes.

The only concern here is the read buffer. We may assume the underlying SetFilePointer() call will be a non-op for a seek-to-current.

When you consult the [source for Seek](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/329c77a859ac60bd.html), you can see that an attempt is made to preserve as much as possible from the read buffer.

Comment: The code does not completely disregard the situation of a no-op seek, but it will always perform a kernel-call to the win32api, which is probably the largest penalty the Seek method can have (besides stream flushing which would happen eventually anyway)

Comment: There is of course some overhead, but even the kernel call will be insignificant compared to doing any actual IO.

Comment: If that's so, the question is pointless. Obviously if no IO is required from the HD, it doesn't matter what .NET's code actually does, because it needs no IO. I believe what the OP wanted to know is if he can gain performance by omitting the Seek when unnecessary.

Comment: @Gilthans: _"If that's so, the question is pointless"_ -- sounds about right.

Comment: @HenkHolterman is right that I was mostly trying to avoid unnecessary IO.  I didn't know enough about IO in Win32 and the .NET stuff on top of it to be sure that seeking to the current location with SeekOrigin.Begin wouldn't require the HD to read the file from the start to that location.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the FileStream.Seek source code over here:
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,329c77a859ac60bd

You can see that regardless of the old position of the file pointer, the SeekCore method is called, which itself calls the Win32Native.SetFilePointer, which is a kernel call.

So the answer is no, it is not optimized, and you should optimize it yourself if you can.

Comment: There is no need to point at 3rd party sites for .net source. [Microsoft provides the source online](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs.html#329c77a859ac60bd)

Comment: I used the first google result, but it is true that it is better to use Microsoft's original documentation. I updated the link

Comment: A easy way to get there, go to http://sourceof.net and it will redirect you to http://referencesource.microsoft.com/